# Can I Use RSocket client to connect to an generic TCP Socket Server using ip and port

Tags: rsocket

I have TCP Socket Server pushing stream of data. This is not a RSocket Server.
Can I use an RSocket client to connect to this server to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

No.  RSocket over TCP uses a specific framing mechanism.  It's the same reason you can't use RSocket over WS to talk to standard websocket server.

https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket/blob/master/Protocol.md